# In Excel, how do I find total class attendance percentage in a particular month?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have prepared a student attendance register in Excel for personal use, the excel file consists of two sheets; 'Attendance' and 'Report'. In the first sheet, the attendance of students is given (from April 2017 to January 2018, and the attendances are just fictitious for the sake of example worksheet).

How can I display a number of working days or lectures delivered in a particular month? for example, how can I display a number of lectures delivered in April month of 2017 and display the result in cell `C25` of second sheet'Report'. I have used formula `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(Attendance!D8:CO8)=MONTH(Attendance!D8)))` for this, but it is giving correct results up to December 2017 only, and wrong results are displayed for January 2018. But as it can be seen from sheet 1, that three lectures were delivered in January 2018.

If possible, please also help to display average attendance of students for a particular month, like for example April, to display the result in the cell `C26` of the second sheet.

The link for excel file is provided below:

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/659869/10+2B%20(April-May).xlsx

**Update:**
Y=Yes, mean lecture was delivered. Now please calculate the number of "Y" in Oct, Nov, Dec 2016 and Jan, Feb 2017. I hope the question is now clear enough.

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--+
|  Date   | 05-10-2016 | 06-10-2016 | 07-11-2016 | 07-11-2016 | 07-12-2016 | 07-12-2016 | 17-01-2017 | 27-02-2017 |  |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--+
| Day     | Wed        | Thurs      | Mon        | Tues       | Wed        | Turs       | Tues       | Mon        |  |
| Lecture | Y          | Y          | Y          | Y          | Y          | Y          | Y          | Y          |  |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--+
```

Comment: This question is hard to understand. (1) It looks like your school is open only three or four days per month (11 days in three months). I’m not sure whether this is important, but it seems so unusual that it makes me wonder whether I’m misunderstanding something. (2) Why is there a blank cell in Sheet1? What do you want done with it? (3) I guess each row in Sheet1 is for one student? Please explain. (4) “I want to calculate a total percentage for the present student …” What do you mean by “the present student”?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) You seem to be saying that you “want to calculate a total percentage …” and then display it in a cell that’s labeled “Number of Working Days”. That doesn’t make sense. (6) As far as I can tell from what you’ve said, you have twelve students, but you want the “total percentage” for only a single student on Sheet2. That really doesn’t make sense. Are you putting averages for the other eleven students on Sheets 3 through 13? Are you trying to calculate a statistic for *all* the students? Please explain. (7) Please show us the formulas you have tried so far.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Explain what they do, and why you can’t make them do what you want.  (8) Please show us an actual, filled-in Sheet2 based on the data in your example Sheet1, explaining where the results come from.  (9) We prefer that you [do not post images of text](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  Post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table) site if you want.

Comment: @Scott: I am sorry I could not express my problem in a proper way. This time I have provided my Excel file through some online hosting website and link is provided. Please see edits.

Comment: Please add a sample data-set and what your expected results would be for that sample. Most people here will not download your whole spreadsheet and especially not from a file-sharing website where they require your email address.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this is not really an improvement. Kevin is right — I don’t want to download your file; I want to understand your question by reading your question. And I wanted it to be clearer. I can’t even tell whether this is the same question. The second paragraph says “number of working days or lectures delivered in a particular month”, which has nothing to do with attendance. And having historical data at future dates is just weird.

Comment: @Scott: The question clearly says that the data is fictitious, nothing is to do with historical or future context. The command I am using is not working when December 2017 change to January 2018.

Comment: @Scott: The question is edited for further update. A small sample data is given now.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I’ll assume that your sample data are in cells `A1:I3`. 
Enter the months in question somewhere; for example, `A5:A9`. 
Enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($B$1:$I$1)=MONTH(A5)), --($B$3:$I$3="Y"))
```

into `B5` and drag/fill down. 
This gets the results you seem to want:

[image: spreadsheet — counting lectures]

by counting the columns where the month is the same as in the current row
and the Lecture Y/N is “Y”.

Comment: I was also using same command `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(Attendance!D8:CO8)=MONTH(Attendance!D8)))`. This command does not give correct result when cell `A5` is formatted using `=TEXT(D8,"ddd")`, in that case this command fails to identify month in cell A5. I will post fresh question with small data.